# Find the keys from array that added together form a given number

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
$array = array(
1=>"a",
2=>"b",
4=>"c",
8=>"d",
16=>"e"
);
```

Then I have the following number $var = 12; This number comes from the sum of keys from the array above. (obviously $var changes).

How can I find the keys that actually create $var.

In the example:

```
12 = array key 4 + array key 8
```

Hope I was clear...

Comment: Are your keys always a binary sequence?

Comment: They keys are the ones shown. They don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary numbers. Magic XD

```
$array = array(1=>"a",2=>"b",4=>"c",8=>"d",16=>"e");
$results = array();
$num = 12;
foreach($array as $i=>$v) {
    if( $num & $i) $results[$i] = $v;
}
// in this case, you get $results = array(4=>"c",8=>"d");
```

Comment: It's a bitwise comparison, checking if that bit is set in the number (ie. that is part of the number)